# PostMan : For Huge data request, I want to have my input in the form of external JSON file and indeed to re-place the entire body per iteration

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

### App Details:

Postman for Win7 /x64

### Issue Report:

1. For Huge data request, I want to have my input in the form of external JSON file and indeed to re-place the entire body per iteration.
2. Expected behavior: body of request, should able to replace by my variable when I run from Collections
3. Screenshots : attached

### Steps to reproduce

1. My Json file in Collection runner as input data :

   ```
       [{
        "rename": {"AssetId": 5496,"NewName": "API-CK9-2st"},
        "addfolderto": {"FolderId": 5456,"FolderName": "API-CK1"}
       }]
   ```
2. And in My Pre-Request Script:

   ```
   var envRename = pm.iterationData.get("rename");
   pm.environment.set("rename", envRename );
   ```
3. And in My Body, I'm trying to use directly the env. variable to replace body like :

   ```
    {{rename}}
   ```
4. Then after running the script, my request body is replaced as:

   ```
       Request Body:"[object Object]"
   ```

   instead of my input json .

### Screenshot link:

[image: Postman Console log with my comments]

Please help me to resolve this, for Huge data request, I want to have my input in the form of external JSON file and indeed to re-place the entire body per iteration.

Comment: This looks wrong to me in the pre-request script `{{envRename}}` the double curly brackets are not needed here. Also I don't believe that you use an object as the value in a data file - I might be wrong though.

Comment: Also you're picking from JSON, I think the way you're getting the date in the `rename` variable is not correct.

Comment: The variable from the file would be used anyway so you shouldn't need to get it and store it as a new environment variable in the pre-request script.

Comment: @DannyDainton: yes I have update the post, that was a typo `{{envRename}}` is not needed there. And its okay of using environment variable in the pre-request script just for modularity purpose and I dont think we can use directly `pm.iterationData.get("rename");` in body... POSTMAN is throwing error

Comment: I don't think you understand what I meant by that comment. Basically what you added in your pre-request script is pointless. If you deleted it and kept the `{{rename}}` in your request body, It would still pick up the data file variable when you execute it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function on the `iterationData` variable and then use the `{{...}}` syntax in the Request Body.

Here's an example of this locally using a different API but using the same approach it should work for what you need.

If you don't wrap your `iterationData` variable with the the `JSON.stringify()` function, you will see `[object Object]` sent as the POST Request Body data:

[image]

---

Here's my solution:

Adding the `JSON.stringify()` function to the `Pre-Request Script` tab and wrapping `pm.interationData.get('my_object')` with it like this:

[image]

Then add the `{{new_object}}` syntax variable to the Request Body, This value has now been JSON stringify'd:

[image]

In the `Collection Runner`, Select the Data File you wish to use. I'm using a JSON file with the `key` 'my_object' and the `value` as a JSON object rather than a single value - You can see the preview of this file here:

[image]

When the Collection or Request is run from the `Collection Runner`, it takes this object value and uses this in the Request Body. As I have used the `JSON.stringify()` function in the `Pre-Request Script`, it's not going to come through as the `[object Object]` that we saw at the start.

[image]

Comment: :I have even used `JSON.stringify` for me no luck...and in my initial post there was a typo of using  `{{envRename}}` instead of using var variable. So when you tried looks like you have also observed that its going as object right? if any solution please let me know.   I hope you have seen the screenshot in the original post

Comment: This worked fine for me - I'll recreate my solution locally and update my answer.

Comment: Yeah sure, awaiting your replay

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: No, that was still going as `[object, object]`

Comment: I don’t really see how that’s possible, did you follow the updated answer that I added - It clearly demonstrates that not happening. There must be something else that you’re doing it your set up that’s causing this not to happen.

Answer (score 2):

It's necessary to change the variable name. So if iterationData contains `rename` variable then it should be renamed to `foo`. then in the body of the postman call, use {{foo}}
The iterationData variable scope overrides all other scopes.